# Python Optimization: Parsing a text file to store default values and create key-pair dictionary in python

Tags: python, text, text-parsing

I am developing a program for which I need to store user defaults and the user should also have the option to modify the defaults for future use of the program. So basically, I have a module to manage default parameters and other aspects of the program that requires certain parts to be stored and later retrieved. For example, to manage the default parameters, I have a file `params.py` in a module to manage `params.txt`. The python file `params.py` essentially contains two functions: (1) `get_default_param(param_name)` and (2) `set_default_param(param_name)`.

The `params.txt` file contains the following:

```
NDIV: 120
EXT: txt
UNITS: cm/s2
AM: 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0
```

`params.py` file contains:

```
def get_default_param_values():
    default_val = {}
    # Get params function
    with open("data/defaults/params.csv") as f1:
        for line in f1:
            split_line = line.split(':')
            default_val[split_line[0]] = [x.strip(" ") for x in split_line[1].strip('\n').split(',')]
    return default_val
```

So in my `main.py` program I call the `params.py` which is located in `data` package inside a `default` folder as

```
from data.defaults.params import get_default_param_values

default_values = get_default_param_values()

for i in range(0,1000):
    #
    # use default_values in the program. These values also gets passed down to other functions
    #
```

If these were not to be modified I could have them easily placed them within a python file and imported the variable. What would be the best of doing it when we would need to modify it at a later stage by the user in front-end?

And another issues is that some of the values for the keys are numbers. How do i automatically identify integers or decimal numbers and convert string to int/float?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it mandatory to store the key-value pairs in a text file?

If yes, what you have already done might be a way to do it.

If not, I'd suggest you to store it as a JSON file and load it as a python dictionary (this approach wards off int parsing issue as well).

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It's not necessary that I need them stored in a text file. I just need an efficient way to store, edit and retrieve. I have never used pickle. Let me try that as well!

Comment: I'd say go for a JSON file. Pickles are stored as binary, and cannot be modified as per your use case. I realised it when I read your question again.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [pyyaml](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/). It's a more readable superset of json.